# Why are my PHP errors appearing in several different files?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-logging, error-log

I was trying to debug a custom WordPress PHP file in `/public_html/wp-content/plugins/myfolder/inc` but for some reason the errors weren't appearing in the usual `public_html/php_errorlog` file.

After some searching, I found that the file was instead writing all of its errors, exception, warnings, and error_log output to `public_html/wp-admin/php_errorlog` instead.

I also noticed a third `php_errorlog` file in `wp-includes`, though nothing had written to it in over a month.

What could be causing it to write to different locations, and how can I make it only write to `public_html/php_errorlog`?

**Edit:** Upon further testing with `getcwd()`, it appears that it always chooses to log to a file in the current directory. So I now have a rough idea of what's going on, but I need to know what file or setting is responsible for that so that I can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a "perk" of some webhosting services (I found this behavior mostly on cheap shared ones).

The error log is being stored in the directory in which the error occurred. The setting responsible for it is `error_log = error_log` in php.ini

Source: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/troubleshoot-php-errors

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I'm working on figuring out how to edit our php.ini file through cPanel.

Comment: That may be even not possible depending on your host.